# Python Flask not loading CSS despite following other tutorials?

Tags: flask

I looked at some other questions here and followed them but my app is still not loading CSS and I do not know what is wrong. My directory is as follows.

(index.html and edit.html here)/static/css (style.css and animate.css here)

```
mainfolder/templates
```

my HTML code to load the CSS is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}"> 
and     
<link 
    rel="stylesheet" 
    href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/animate.css') }}">
```

Comment: This is a bit ambiguous.  Is it mainfolder/templates and mainfolder/static or are you saying that static is inside the templates folder or in a different directory than mainfolder?

Comment: @LoganBertram The static is inside the templates folder

Comment: the default `static` directory should **NOT** be inside the template folder... if you want to keep it that way you'll need to remap the "static" directory upon instantiating your Flask instance: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask

Comment: @abigperson I moved the statics directory into the main folder, it is still not loading

Comment: Have you done anything to change the default static folder configuration?  Can you render your page?  If so, what is the rendered path for the css links?  If not what is the debug output?

Comment: @LoganBertram I created the static folder my self? index.html loads, but the CSS is not loaded in. I moved the static folder to mainfolder, now mainfolder contains templates and static but the CSS is still not loading

Comment: The css is located under static/css

Comment: When index.html loads, inspect the page, and see what is rendered for the css path.

Answer (score 0):

In Flask, [static files](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_static_files.htm) such as JavaScript files or CSS files are served from the `static` folder in your package or next to your module and it will be available at `/static` in the application.

A special endpoint `static` is used to generate URLs for static files. For example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'style.css') }}">
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{ url_for('static', filename = 'bootstrap.js') }}" ></script>
```

You need to enter the type of static file when providing the URL of this files. For example:

For CSS: `type="text/css"`

For JavaScript: `type = "text/javascript"`

If it still doesn't load, try [hard reloading the page](https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers). The shortcut keys for different browsers for hard reloading the browser can be found on this page. The shortcut in Chrome (for Windows) to hard-reload is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>